# Strange GLSL behaviour with arrays and conditions

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I am developing a small OpenGL engine and currently stuck at the following GLSL problem:

I am trying to implement a shader for multiple lights and it generates the correct result but only if I put the calculation of the diffuse light inside an (completely useless) if statement. The specultar light component is always correctly rendered.

Works:

```
for( int i = 0; i < uNumLights; ++i ) {
   //...
   if( <anything> == <something> ) {
      lDiffuseLight  += vAmbientDiffuseMaterial * uLights[i].color * lIntensity;
   }
}
```

Does not work:

```
for( int i = 0; i < uNumLights; ++i ) {
   //...
   lDiffuseLight  += vAmbientDiffuseMaterial * uLights[i].color * lIntensity;
}
```

Furthermore it has no effect if I use a constant instead of an uniform for the loop condition.

Why does the code with the if work and without the if not? How can I make my shader work without silly if statements?

The full shader code:

The Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330
const int MAX_LIGHTS = 4;

in vec3 iVertex;
in vec3 iNormals;

uniform mat4 uModelView;
uniform mat4 uMVP;
uniform mat3 uNormal;

smooth out vec3 vPosition;
smooth out vec3 vModelView;
smooth out vec3 vNormals;

// Colors...

smooth out vec3 vAmbientDiffuseMaterial; // Make some colors...
smooth out vec3 vAmbientLight;
smooth out vec3 vLightDirection[MAX_LIGHTS];

uniform vec3 uAmbientColor;

uniform int uNumLights;

uniform struct Light {
   vec3 color;
   vec3 position;
} uLights[MAX_LIGHTS];

void main(void) {
   vAmbientDiffuseMaterial = clamp(iVertex, 0.0, 1.0);

   vAmbientLight = vAmbientDiffuseMaterial * uAmbientColor;

   gl_Position = uMVP * vec4( iVertex.xyz, 1.0 );

   vPosition  = gl_Position.xyz;
   vNormals   = normalize( uNormal    * iNormals );
   vModelView = ( uModelView * vec4( iVertex , 1 )).xyz;

   for( int i = 0; i < uNumLights; ++i ) {
      vLightDirection[i] = normalize( uLights[i].position - vModelView );
   }
}
```

The fragment shader:

```
#version 330

const int MAX_LIGHTS = 4;

uniform mat4 uModelView;

out vec4 oFinalColor;

smooth in vec3 vPosition;
smooth in vec3 vModelView;
smooth in vec3 vNormals;

smooth in vec3 vAmbientDiffuseMaterial;
smooth in vec3 vAmbientLight;
smooth in vec3 vLightDirection[MAX_LIGHTS];

// Light stuff

uniform int uNumLights;

uniform struct Light {
   vec3 color;
   vec3 position;
} uLights[MAX_LIGHTS];

const vec3 cSpecularMaterial = vec3( 0.9, 0.9, 0.9 );
const float cShininess       = 30.0;


void main(void) {
   vec3 lReflection, lSpecularLight = vec3( 0 ), lDiffuseLight = vec3( 0 );
   float lIntensity;

   // Specular Light
   for( int i = 0; i < uNumLights; ++i ) {
      lReflection     = normalize( reflect( -vLightDirection[i], vNormals) );
      lIntensity      = max( 0.0, dot( -normalize(vModelView), lReflection ) );

      lSpecularLight += cSpecularMaterial * uLights[i].color * pow( lIntensity, cShininess );

      // Diffuse Light
      lIntensity      = max( 0, dot( vNormals, vLightDirection[i] ) );

      // Here is the strange if part:
      // Only with the if lDiffuseLight is what it is supposed to be.
      if( uLights[i].color != vec3( 0, 0, 0 ) ) {
         lDiffuseLight  += vAmbientDiffuseMaterial * uLights[i].color * lIntensity;
      }
   }

   oFinalColor = vec4( vAmbientLight + lDiffuseLight + lSpecularLight, 1 );
}
```

I have tested all uniforms and they are all correct set in the shader.

Comment: @waaitt what errors? (especially 'a lot' part - there's only 3 places where it *could* be wrong, and it isn't). Looks fine to me. Compiles with `cgc` just as well.

Comment: Have you considered attempting to reproduce problem on e.g. shadertoy? It shouldn't be as you describe, if not some weird NaN or something completely unrelated happens.

Comment: Made some more tests with a Intel GPU and the free nouveau driver and the proprietary NVidia driver: The bug only occurs on Machines with the proprietary NVidia driver. All other configurations are working fine.

Comment: Try clearing shader cache (`~/.nv/GLCache` for *nix, `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\NVIDIA Corporation\NV_Cache` for windows). If problem persists, consider moving it into standalone example and maybe filing a bug report.

Comment: Clearing the cache did not help. I will create a bug report